# Telerik MVC3 Grid Differentiating Filtered Column Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

Can anybody suggest me the possibilities to differentiate the filtered Telerik grid column with other columns. Meaning that I can provide different color scheme to differentiate the filtered column.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as someone who has had to deal with the Telerik MVC grid in a similar manner, I will share with you my solution for doing this:

1) Run the web page that has your grid, and view the source.

2) Find out, by viewing the source, what exactly happens when the filter is turned on (i.e. an attribute change, some function being called, etc.).

3) Using jQuery, set the color scheme of that column when that event occurs.

It's rather annoying that you can't just do it using Telerik's control itself, but this should help you out.